# Keycloak console doesnt open accessed remotely for the first time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, keycloak

Keycloak console doesn't open accessed remotely for the first time.

Installed keycloak as docker run on port 8080 on google cloud server, added user using script but still login console doesn't open and shows error.

Same is happening if deployed on kubernetes on Google cloud

Could someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you publish the container port [container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports), on GCP enable the port into the [VPC firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) in order to allow the external traffic reach you VM on the port you specify and internally the traffic get you containter with the service.

(Service)/Container [port/port]<--> VM [External IP/port]<--> Internet <--> Client

You can run some test like nmap to scan the external IP with the port you specified. Inside the VM you can use a [netstat](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/) to verify the port is listening on the VM.

If the VM have a internal firewall you need to open the port as well, check which Linux distribution yo have and look if the firewall is active.